# How to insert hex data into blob data type column in Cassandra via pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, blob, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to insert a hex string into a Cassandra table with blob datatype column.   The Cassandra table structure is as follows:

CREATE TABLE mob.sample (
id text PRIMARY KEY,
data blob
);

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


def hexstrtohexnum(hexstr):
    ani = int(hexstr[2:],16)
    return(ani)

# Create a DataFrame using SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .appName('SampleLoader')
         .appName('SparkCassandraApp')
         .getOrCreate())


schema = StructType([StructField("id",StringType(),True),
                     StructField("data",StringType(),True)])

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([("key1", '0x546869732069732061206669727374207265636f7264'),
                                 ("key2", '0x546865207365636f6e64207265636f7264'),
                                 ("key3", '0x546865207468697264207265636f7264')],schema)

hexstr2hexnum = udf(lambda z: hexstrtohexnum(z),IntegerType())
spark.udf.register("hexstr2hexnum", hexstr2hexnum)
df.withColumn("data",hexstr2hexnum("data"))
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace='mob',table='sample').save(mode="append")
```

When I run the code above it's giving an error:

```
WARN  2020-09-03 19:41:57,902 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 441, 10.37.122.156, executor 2): com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object 0x546869732069732061206669727374207265636f7264 of type class java.lang.String to java.nio.ByteBuffer.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:44)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$ByteBufferConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$11.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:258)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:42)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$ByteBufferConverter$.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(TypeConverter.scala:255)
```

Here's the contents of the dataframe.

```
>>> df.show(3)
+----+--------------------+
|  id|                data|
+----+--------------------+
|key1|0x546869732069732...|
|key2|0x546865207365636...|
|key3|0x546865207468697...|
+----+--------------------+
```

Can someone help me what's wrong with my code?  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Reading a test record the blob type appears as BinaryType rather than StringType

```
>>> table1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="blobtest",keyspace="test").load()
>>> table1.show()
+----+--------------------+
|  f1|                  f2|
+----+--------------------+
|1234|[54 68 69 73 20 6...|
+----+--------------------+

>>> print(table1.schema)
StructType(List(StructField(f1,StringType,false),StructField(f2,BinaryType,true)))
```

Change your schema to BinaryType and you should be able to write it

```
>>> string = "This is a test."
>>> arr = bytearray(string, 'utf-8')
>>> schema = StructType([StructField("f1",StringType(),True),StructField("f2",BinaryType(),True)])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("key3",arr)],schema)
>>> df.show()
        +----+--------------------+
        |  f1|                  f2|
        +----+--------------------+
        |key3|[54 68 69 73 20 6...|
        +----+--------------------+
        
>>> df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace='test',table='blobtest2').save(mode="append")
```

Comment: The solution only works if the string is an ascii string.   But when the string is a hex blob string and you want the hex blob string to be stored as is into the blob column it does not work.  Is there a possibility to store the hex blob string as is into the blob column?

Comment: Use bytearray.fromhex to convert the hex string to bytearray eg  df = spark.createDataFrame([("key4",bytearray.fromhex("546869732069732061206669727374207265636f7264"))],schema)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to fix this problem.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import binascii

def hextobinary(hexstr):
    a = binascii.unhexlify(hexstr[2:])
    return(a)

# Create a DataFrame using SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .appName('SampleLoader')
         .appName('SparkCassandraApp')
         .getOrCreate())


schema = StructType([StructField("id",StringType(),True),
                     StructField("data",StringType(),True)])

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([("key1", '0x546869732069732061206669727374207265636f7264'),
                            ("key2", '0x546865207365636f6e64207265636f7264'),
                            ("key3", '0x546865207468697264207265636f7264')],schema)
print(df)

tobinary = udf(lambda z: hextobinary(z),BinaryType())
spark.udf.register("tobinary", tobinary)
df1 = df.withColumn("data",tobinary("data"))
print(df1)
df1.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(keyspace='mob',table='sample').save(mode="append")
```